# Good Usenet client for binaries on Ubuntu ( like Xnews )

Tags: ubuntu, usenet

I've been an Xnews user for many years.

The reason I'm not switching all of my computers to Ubuntu is that I cannot find a decent Usenet client for binary files.

Any sugggetions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few:

- [Klibdo](http://klibido.sourceforge.net/)
- [NZB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nzb/)
- [newsleecher (running under WINE)](http://www.newsleecher.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13822)

and of course:

- [xnews (running under WINE)](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Windows-Newsreaders-under-Linux-HOWTO/xnews.html)

Answer (score 2):

SABnzbd is the best USENET binaries client you will find and it is cross platform.

http://www.sabnzbd.org/download/

Comment: I'm checkin' this out right now

Comment: Don't be put off by the default theme. Switch it to plush. It is much prettier.

Answer (score 0):

http://pan.rebelbase.com/ minimal and good. however gets stuck sometimes on Ubuntu.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.